Migrating from runOnDataset() to evaluate() - getting "TypeError: evaluator is not a function"
We're trying to migrate our LangSmith-JS tests from using runOnDataset() to evaluate(). Unfortunately, the documentation does not seem very clear to me, at least not for JavaScript.
Here is what we used to do:
const correctnessEvaluator = LabeledCriteria('correctness', {
  formatEvaluatorInputs: (payload) => ({
    prediction: payload.rawPrediction.output,
    input: JSON.stringify(payload.rawInput),
    reference: payload.rawReferenceOutput.output,
  }),
});

return await runOnDataset(
  getTextOutputFromBot,
  datasetName,
  {
    evaluators: [correctnessEvaluator],
  },
);

The above worked and gave us results in LangSmith in the Correctness column.
Here is what I am trying to run now:
return await evaluate(async (inputs) =>
  await getTextOutput({ question: inputs.question }), {
  data: dataset,
  evaluators: [correctnessEvaluator],
  experimentPrefix: dataset.substring(0, dataset.indexOf('Dataset')),
  numRepetitions: 1,
});

I get the following error when I run the above:
  console.error
    Error running evaluator evaluateRun on run bc7b97db-45db-4f30-a66d-a8099dd29228: TypeError: evaluator is not a function

      146 |     summaryEvaluators?: any;
      147 |   }) => {
    > 148 |     return await evaluate(async (inputs) =>
          |            ^
      149 |       await getTextOutput({ question: inputs.question }), {
      150 |       data: dataset,
      151 |       evaluators: Array.isArray(evaluators) ? evaluators : [evaluators],

      at _ExperimentManager._runEvaluators (node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:418:25)
      at _ExperimentManager._score (node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:439:17)
      at makeIter (node_modules/langsmith/dist/utils/atee.cjs:9:32)
      at node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:309:34
      at _ExperimentManager.getResults (node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:339:30)
      at ExperimentResults.processData (node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:608:26)
      at _evaluate (node_modules/langsmith/dist/evaluation/_runner.cjs:646:5)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?
